# Does every Euclidean unitary 2D CFT lie on the Principal or Supplementary series?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory

**TLDR:** *why is the principal series hardly mentioned in a large portion of the 2D CFT literature? Are the unitary representations of the local conformal group still a combination of Principal series representations?*

The global conformal group of 2D Euclidean space is $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. Gel'fand et al (Generalized functions Vol.5) classified all unitary representations of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. A short summary of this classification is that each representation can be classified by two numbers $(\triangle,\sigma)$, where in a certain basis the action of $\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ reads

\begin{equation}U\Big[\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}\Big]\vert z,\triangle,\sigma\rangle=(cz+d)^{\triangle+\sigma}(\bar{c}\bar{z}+\bar{d})^{\triangle-\sigma}\vert \frac{az+b}{cz+d},\triangle,\sigma\rangle\end{equation}

Gel'fand 'et al proved that a unitary inner product exists for these representation if and only if $\triangle=-1+i\mathbb{R},\sigma\in\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2}$  referred to as the Principal series. There is also another subset for which a unitary inner product exists called the supplementary series, but I will just refer to the principal series for brevity.

I am confused by the fact that the majority of the 2D CFT literature I have read does not mention the phrase principal series. e.g. Di Francesco's big CFT book or Ginsparg's "Applied Conformal Field Theory" notes do not mention the series. This makes me question whether the principal series is still secretly there? Or does the principal series ($\triangle=-1+i\mathbb{R},\sigma\in\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2}$) become irrelevant when one enhances the global conformal group to the local conformal group? Or is it that all unitary $2D$ CFT's of Euclidean space are still some combination of Principal series representations, but it just is not the simplest description of the representations when one enhances from the global to the local conformal group? Do new inner products arise when one enhances from global to local?

Comment: Not a full answer, but until quite recently, people were most comfortable expressing the operator content of CFTs using representations of highest weight type.

Comment: What I infer from your comment is that the representations still are a combination of principal series representations, but in a basis where this language is not considered very useful.

Comment: I would support that based on recent work preforming harmonic analysis on the 4pt function. Instead of a discrete sum of highest weight conformal blocks, it can also be written as an integral of principal series conformal blocks times a kernel. You go between the two languages by closing the contour which picks up the poles of this kernel.

Comment: This article by Hollans and Lechner may be relevant https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-017-2942-6

Comment: I think A. Gadde reviews this very clearly in his paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07362